# What is "Luncheon meat detected" in SmokeDetector on Chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, spam-detection, smokedetector

I recently noticed an odd warning by the SmokeDetector bot about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581453/apply-templates-that-matchs-two-conditions):

[image: "Luncheon meat detected" report by SmokeDetector]

What does this mean? Should I be worried about it?

Comment: Related, for those with Charcoal Team access: https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/charcoal/questions/287

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=48477270#48477270) in the Charcoal HQ transcript:

> scaaahu
>
> > What does " Luncheon meat detected" generally mean? Spam? R/A? or just suspicious? or something else? This was my misunderstandings from.
>
> Robert Longson
>
> > The intent is to catch "hashes" left at the end of the post. It's FP prone...It's there to catch a specific troll that writes posts with "hashes" at the end. "Hashes" being a group of random letters without spaces.

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/q/287/98) but you need a special account with Charcoal.

Comment: For what it's worth "FP-prone" means prone to false positives, i.e. Smoke Detector reporting posts as possible spam which are actually fine.